# Pyqt5 QToolButton set style sheet with the autoRaise method

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a stylesheet `.qss` file for the GUI. I am trying to add the `QToolButton` method `autoRaise` to the style sheet as:

```
btn_on  = QToolButton()
btn_on.setStyleSheet("""
                 QToolButton:autoRaised{
                 color: rgb(0,0,0);
                 background-color: rgb(142,142,142);
                 }
                 """)
btn_on.setAutoRaise(True)
```

But it doesn't recognize the `autoRaise` attribute. This is same as you define a `disabled` attribute for the `QPushButton`, which is working:

```
ss = QPushButton()
ss.setStyleSheet("""
                 QToolButton:autoRaised{
                 color: rgb(0,0,0);
                 background-color: rgb(142,142,142);
                 }
                 """)
ss.setDisabled(True)
```

How can I define the `autoRaise` attribute inside the `.qss` file?

Comment: Thanks. I have added it in the file, and call the .qss. But when I change the state of the button (button.setAutoRaise(False)), it is not changing?

Comment: See my answer, I've expanded the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autoRaise` (*without* a final "D") is a Qt *property*.

The `:syntax` is used for *pseudo states*, normally indicating a state of the widget or a generic property.
They are predefined and common to all widgets, even if some states are only supported by some widgets (like `:read-only` for a text widget) and based on the CSS pseudo-classes; see the full [list of supported pseudo states](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states).

If you want to set the style based on a property, you must properly use the [property selector syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types):

```
    QToolButton[autoRaise="true"] {
        color: rgb(0,0,0);
        background-color: rgb(142,142,142);
    }
```

Note that styles might override some painting or completely ignore the color in some situations. For instance, on Linux with the Oxygen and Breeze styles, the hovered style ignores the color and uses the default painting.

Also note that stylesheets are evalued only once, so if the property changes the change won't be reflected: you need to re-set the stylesheet again. This *cannot* be done automatically.

```
    btn_on.setAutoRaise(False)
    btn_on.setStyleSheet(btn_on.styleSheet())
```

If the stylesheet is set on a parent or the application and the target widget has no stylesheet set, you must re-set the stylesheet for that parent or the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation